# How can I set up a table using a series of ID's CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a a table using a series styled div ID's in CSS. I'm having real trouble styling the divs. Could someone tell me if I'm approaching this the correct way?

Baring in mind the 'table' will be used to retrieve live data, well hopefully! so I may need the column widths to automatically adjust to fit the character length of a generated string.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   Top Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Column one            |             Column two              |  Column Three
```

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
            <div id="top_row">
                <h3>Top row</h3>
            </div>
                <div id="column_one">
                    <h3>column one</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="column_two">
                    <h3>column two</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="column_three">
                    <h3>column three</h3>
                </div>

          </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {

    display: table;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    }

    #top_row {
    display: table-row;
    }

    #column_one, #column_two, #column_three {

    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    letter-spacing:1.5px;
```

Comment: * I'm trying to align the table centrally on the page

Comment: Add margin auto on #container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not. I'd add a proper row for the bottom part, though:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jcg8Y/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top_row">
         <h3>Top row</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="bottom_row">
        <div id="column_one">
             <h3>column one</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="column_two">
             <h3>column two</h3>

        </div>
        <div id="column_three">
             <h3>column three</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```